# Finding all parents in mysql table for all records with single query (Recursive Query)

Tags: mysql, sql, tree

I have table [category], which has fields [id, name, parent_id] - hierarchical data.
I have this hierarchical query which find all parents for child with id=259:

```
SELECT  _id AS id, parent_id,
        @cl := @cl + 1 AS level
FROM    (
        SELECT  @r AS _id,
                    (
                SELECT  @r := parent_id
                FROM    category
                WHERE   id = _id
                ) AS parent_id,
                @l := @l + 1 AS level
        FROM    (
                SELECT  @r := 259,
                        @l := 0,
                        @cl := 0
                ) vars,
                category h
        WHERE   @r <> 0
        ORDER BY
                level DESC
        ) qi
```

So my questions are:

1. How to retrieve parents for all records from the table [category], not only for the record with id=259?
2. How to include name field in this record set?

Comment: what does `select version();` say?

Comment: @ysth - 5.7.24.

Comment: Any option to upgrade?

Comment: Does it mean there no solution without upgrade?

Comment: There are solutions without upgrade (see answers to the duplicate question - not just the accepted one!), however you need wrapper functions or procedures to make those work for the entire table. With a recursive CTE in mysql v8.0, it is a lot simpler task.

Comment: What about second question: How to include name field in this query?